# In postman - how can we combine the pre-request scripts and the body?

Tags: postman-pre-request-script

I am getting error while I tried to pluck the pre-request-script and then put in the body.
Invalid request: at least one field format is invalid
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRqBD.png)

It should run as a single request after merging the pre-request and the body inside postman